# How to plot with tikz without graduations in the axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to plot a function with `tikz` and let the plot as clean as possible, but I can't remove the lines along the axis. Can anyone help with this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[    
    axis lines = center,
    xticklabels=none,
    yticklabels=none,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$y$},
    scale=0.8,
]
\addplot [
    domain=-2.5:2.5,
    samples=500, 
    color=red,
]
{-x^4 + 5*x^3 + 8*x^2 - 20*x -3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `xtick=\empty` and `ytick=\empty` to the axis options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of `xtick=<list>` and `ytick=<list>`, `pgfplots` uses its normal method of calculating tick positions, so you get the marks even though you've zeroed out the tick label text.

Add  `xtick=\empty` and `ytick=\empty` to the axis options to override.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[    
    axis lines = center,
    xticklabels=none,
    yticklabels=none,
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$y$},
    scale=0.8,
]
\addplot [
    domain=-2.5:2.5,
    samples=500, 
    color=red,
]
{-x^4 + 5*x^3 + 8*x^2 - 20*x -3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]